# Azure's DNS issue after creating snapshot and redeploying the VM with a new IP

Tags: linux, powershell, azure, ssh, dns

I have created a VM in azure named `hostmaster` having a private IP address and can be accessible by `supermaster`(Another VM in azure within the same subnet). The hostname of the VM is `master_machine`. I followed the steps from this link - https://blog.kloud.com.au/2017/06/09/the-quickest-way-to-create-new-vms-in-azure-from-existing-vm-snapshots-mostly-with-powershell/ to create a snapshot and recreate a new VM while the old one is existing.

The new VM is created successfully and it's name is `hostmaster_copy`. However, the hostname is same i.e. `master_machine`. This is having a different IP from a different subnet than the old VM. I tried to do ssh from `supermachine` and gave `ssh master_machine` and I am logged into the new VM but not the old one.

I am able to login to the old VM only through the IP from `supermaster`. All the DNS settings are gone for the old one. Is there a way to restore or reset the DNS settings of the old VM?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> All the DNS settings are gone for the old one. Is there a way to
>   restore or reset the DNS settings of the old VM?

If you want to reset the private DNS, we can modify the `/etc/hostname` and reboot this VM, after this server reboot completed, we can use the new hostname to access this VM in the same subnet.

---

**Update:**

As we know, snapshot will **not** generalize this VM, so when we use this to create new VM, the new VM's settings same as your original VM.

If you want to use this VM as an image to create more VMs, we should prepare(**generalize**) this VM, and use this VM to create a new image, after that we can use this new image to create VMs, in this way new VMs will get the new private DNS automatically.

About create Azure image, please refer to this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/linux/capture-image).

---

**Update2**:

In your scenario, here a **workaround**:

We can modify your VM hostname to `master_machine1` and restart it. After it running, modify the hostname to `master_machine` and restart it again, in this way, the private DNS will work correctly.

**Snapshot** only work for a signal disk, if your VM have os disk and a data disk, we should create snapshots for them.

After snapshots created, we can use snapshots to create new VM and new data disk, then attach data disk to new VM.

Also we can copy Snapshots to another storage account as a blob to keep backups of the base blob. You can also copy a snapshot over its base blob, which is like restoring the blob to an earlier version. When a snapshot is copied from one storage account to another, it occupies the same space as the base page blob. Therefore, copying whole snapshots from one storage account to another is slow and consumes much space in the target storage account.

More information about Azure snapshot, please refer to this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/windows/incremental-snapshots#incremental-snapshot-copy).

Comment: the `etc/hostname` already has the hostname and after successful reboot also the hostname is not retained. I edited the `/etc/hosts` and added the IP  alongwith the hostname and now I am able to use it. But I wanted azure to take care of the hostname and I should not do it manually.

Comment: @wonder Azure does not recommend use snapshot to create other VMs,because snapshot have same settings with your original VM, if you want to create other VMs, we can use that VM to create a image, then use this image to create new VMs, in this way, new VM will get the private DNS automatically. To create the image, we can follow this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/linux/capture-image).

Comment: I wanted to create a backup of the VM to get an exact replica of it. As you said, "snapshot have same settings with your original VM" what are all those settings. The image also restores the applications, user accounts and most of the other things. What are the other settings which snapshot restores and not the image??

Comment: @wonder if you want to get an exact replica of your VM, you are right, we should use snapshot. if we have not generalize your VM, the image will have the same VM name, same user account and password, same settings in `/etc/resolv.conf`, same cached DHCP client leases. So if we want to use this image to create more VMs, we should prepare this VM then use this VM create image. But if you just want to create a backup of your VM, I think snapshot is the right way, after you use this snapshot  create the new VM, we should change those settings or shutdown your original VM.

Comment: Ok so in my case I shouldn't have started the VM and that's why I faced this DHCP issue. Now is there a way to restore the DNS settings?

Comment: @wonder restore the DNS settings? do you mean you want to use `master_machine` to ssh to your old VM? have you modify the new VM's host name and restart it? if yes, then please restart your old VM and try `ssh master_machine` again.

Comment: I have not modified the hostname of my new VM. I have actually removed it after seeing the DNS issues. Do you mean to say if I do the hostname changes in my new VM, Will it update the DNS name resolution settings in Azure's DNS records for the old one and new one?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/152699/discussion-between-jason-ye-msft-and-wonder).

Comment: @wonder No, change new VM's hostname and restart it, the DNS settings just work for new VM, old VM will not get update, so we should restart old VM to update the DNS settings.